# windowsphone - how to change app view without .xaml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have a question , i want to know how  can i change the application view (For example in a simple Grid in app) without creating or Navigating between .xaml !

thanks a lot !

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: because i want to create the application toolbar in bottom of app like an iOS application when clicked on each ApplicationBarIconButton i don't want to redirect and navigate to other app i want to show another view like iOS !!! @AmanKhandelwal

Comment: that means you need to create multiple views in a single page?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal yes ! (maybe something like panorama or pivot pages !)!

Answer (score 2):

Create and manage controls in code behind. Each xaml control is a class. You can delete them or add them.

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox(); 
GridName.Children.Add( tb );
...
```

Comment: please explain more?!! @crea7or

Answer (score 0):

Grid Layout could be the best fit for your needs

The children controls inside the grid spans over the complete grid if the grid is not attributed with Row/Column definitions

For Example

if this is your layoutRoot

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
 </Grid>
```

then you can make 2 views in a single layoutroot tag and control their Visibility accordingly. Just remove the row definitions and put two stackpanels. Now these stackpanels spans over the complete grid.

Something like this helps

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Name="Page1" Background="Red" Visibility="Visible">
        <Image Source="/BurgundyShadeTableLamp3535722.jpg"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="Page2" Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Button Content="Button"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Below are the two images which describes your solution better.

Making the first stackpanel Visible

[image]

Making the Second stackpanel Visible

[image]

Same Grid, Same Page and multiple views inside, you can customize each stackpanel inside and control their visibility.

No  need to do anything from the code behind

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot but can i put a simple image view or other objects in StackPanel?

Comment: Yes, you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: yes stackpanel is also a parent control, its easy! answer edited